# Detect when upload finishes

Tags: android

I am uploading an image file to a server in android.
I want to know when the upload completes.Is there any way to know that.
if there any state in android that automatically calls when the upload completes.
 OR how to check this state.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using HttpClient.execute(), it's a synchronous method - it returns once the upload is done.

EDIT: there's no asynchronous HTTP client on Android, as far as I know. For non-blocking upload, use HttpClient is a worker thread, and use Handler.post(Runnable) to process the completion back in the main thread.

EDIT2: the async HTTP looks like this:

```
final Handler Ha = new Handler(); //Used to post the results back to the main thread
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run()
    {
        HttpPost pr = new HttpPost(MyURL);
        pr.setEntity(MyUploadData);
        //More request setup...
        HttpResponse Resp = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(pr);
        //Process response here... detect errors, for one thing
        Ha.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                //This executes back in the main thread!
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: then what is the asynchronous method, can you please explain.

Comment: I am using HttpClient.execute()

Comment: Thanks. But I have one more doubt how can we know the bytes transferred each time.

Comment: @James: during upload? IIRC you cannot.